# Objective C - Calling dispatch_async show error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm using dispatch_async to do something on other tread.

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
```

In the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("dispatchName", NULL);
}
```

Using it:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^
{
    // Do something...
});
```

Everything is OK until I'm calling this method again.
The app is crush with error:

```
2014-09-29 11:34:10.626 hELLO[2785:389790] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
2014-09-29 11:34:10.628 hELLO[2785:389790] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

Comment: You should not perform any UI related code on a background thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to execute process, which can be executed only in main thread. 
Put the code into

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

})
```